# Right way to update a drupal distribution?

Tags: updating, distributions

I have a site which is a [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution.

My distribution version is 7.x-2.0-rc1 and now the 7.x-2.0-rc2 version is available.

How do I update a distribution? I tried these method (both failed...)

1) I follow the update standar process using the drupal ui. I get this error message:

```
>     Notice: Undefined index: version_major in update_calculate_project_update_status() (line 595 of
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite.com/modules/update/update.compare.inc).
>     Downloading updates failed:
>     
>     commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.0-rc2-core.tar.gz does not contain any .info files.
>     Notice: Undefined index: version_major in update_calculate_project_update_status() (line 595 of
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mySite.com/modules/update/update.compare.inc).
```

2) I downloaded the distribution and replace the folder mysite.com/profiles/commerce_kickstart
This didn't work neither.

¿Which is the right way to to do this?

Comment: [Best practice for updating kickstart?](http://drupal.org/node/1821484) should help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try it with drush.

```bsh
drush dl commerce_kickstart
drush updatedb -y
```

(I have not tried it for commerce kickstart; I just got the answer on drupal.org.)

Comment: i'll try it but keep in mind that commerce_kickstart is distribution not a module. I tried this once and I get the modules of the distribution installed in sites/all/modules instead of profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules.

Comment: then may be this is a wrong answer.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. See link provided by Clive. @chefnelone is, I think, thinking of `drush pm-updatecode`, which currently does not work right with distributions.  pm-download should put the commerce_kickstart modules in the right place, because it just unpacks the distro contents. Note that you can use `drush pm-updatecode drupal` to update core, if needed.  Do this before calling updatedb (or use pm-update).  If this does not work, please post a bug report to the Drush issue queue.

Comment: It just worked. Using $ drush dl commerce_kickstart 
$ drush updatedb -y is the correct way. thanks.

Comment: I use a drushrc.php file to make sure modules downloaded with drush go in the contrib folder. This also means that commerce_kickstart would go there if downloaded with drush. The solution is to specify the destination when downloading: `drush dl commerce_kickstart --destination=profiles/`

Answer (score 5):

Commerce Kickstart has a documentation page explaining how to install or update the distribution: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install.
It is linked from the project page on drupal.org.

The updater inside Drupal can't update distributions (or Drupal core itself), so it can't work for Kickstart.

Answer (score 2):

Although "drush pm-download" should work, there is an initiative to have this work with "drush pm-updatecode" as well.  See the issue on Github [Drush up should update contrib profiles as well](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/99) for details.

At the time of this writing, there's nothing available for use, but hopefully there will be usable code soon.  Feel free to contribute to the thread so that we can get this done faster.

Answer (score 1):

**Eleven steps to upgrade a Drupal 7 distribution:**

1. Backup and/or Test locally
2. Read the Release Notes
3. Maintenance / Off-line Mode
4. Copy Sites Folder
5. Delete Existing Files
6. Downloading Updated Distribution Code
7. Restore Sites Folder
8. Run Updates
9. Revert Features
10. Clear Cache
11. Disable Maintenance Mode / Go On-line

Source and details into this official documentation at https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/distributions/maintaining-sites-built-with-distributions#update-distribution